# Cannot index a list with vector[1] of same class as direct character (where the latter can index)

Tags: r, variables

Sorry for the confusing title:

I have a list, `y`, that is indexed by characters, e.g. `y$"100"$VALUE` returns some vector that I am looking for.

However, when I store a vector, `list.index = as.character(...)`, where "..." is a bunch of numbers, I can get `list.index[1] == "100"` to return `TRUE`, but typing `y$list.index[1]$VALUE` does not return the vector I saw above, but instead returns `NULL`.

I am very confused, since I wouldn't think it would matter if the blank in `y$_____$VALUE` were the `"100"` or `list.index[1]` since the two are equivalent. They are both of the class `"character"`.

Any advice? Thanks!

In short:

```
> y$"100"$VALUE
 [1] 10.9950 11.1900 11.1400 10.7100 10.4100  9.3300  9.6700  9.0400  9.2000  9.5400  9.9000  9.8000  9.2600  9.7500  9.2900  9.5900  9.3000  9.2500  9.8800  9.8500
[21]  9.3100 10.1400  9.9800 10.3000  9.3100  9.9000  9.6300  9.6300  9.7500  9.5300  9.4000  9.3500  9.5300  9.4700  9.4000  9.3400  9.3620  9.3900  9.5500  9.7000
[41]  9.5000  9.7699  9.9000  9.6500  9.7000  9.7900  9.5000  9.8500  9.1700  8.9900  8.9000  9.0800  8.7010  8.3000  8.5260  8.5350  8.6120  8.5400  8.9800  8.7600
[61]  9.2584  8.9900  7.5000  8.5000  8.5000

> y$list.index[1]$VALUE
NULL

> class(list.index[1])
[1] "character"

> class("100")
[1] "character"

> list.index[1]
[1] "100"

> class(y)
[1] "list"

> list.index[1] == "100"
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `list.index[1]` is a vector, while the `"100"` in the actual list index is a name.  Is there a reason why you are not using class `numeric`?  And why couldn't you just assign `y$"100"$VALUE` a new variable, say z, and access it that way?  The way you are accessing the list elements is quite unorthodox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the manual (`` ?`$` ``):

> Both `[[` and `$` select a single element of the list. The main difference
>   is that `$` does not allow computed indices, whereas `[[` does.

Therefore `y$list.index[1]$VALUE` doesn't work because `$` looks for a list name that looks like `list.index[1]`. You should instead use `y[[list.index[1]]]$VALUE` or `y[[list.index[1]]][["VALUE"]]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help; I really appreciate it. Kicking myself for not seeing it in manual after quickly becoming overwhelmed.